# How to limit results in reverse relation in Django

Tags: mysql, django

I have two tables, one called `Company` and the other called `User`, each user is related to one company using `ForeignKey`. So I can use reverse relation in Django to get all users for specific company (e.g. `company.users`)

In my case, I'm building `ListAPIView` which return multiple companies, and I'd like to return latest created user. My problem is that I don't want to use `prefetch_related` or `select_related` so it will load all the users, as we might end up having thousands of users per each company! Also I don't want to load each latest user in a separate query so we end up having tens of queries per API request!

I've tried something like this:

```
users_qs = models.User.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('-created')
company_qs = models.Company.objects.prefetch_related(
                 Prefetch('users', queryset=users_qs[:1], to_attr='user')
             ).order_by('-created')
```

In this case, `prefetch_related` failed as we can't set limit on the `Prefetch`'s `queryset` filter (it gives this error "Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.")

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are providing an object instead of a queryset `Prefetch('users', queryset=users_qs[:1], to_attr='user')`